# Firewall error in RHEL 7.2: "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: firewall, iptables, rhel, nagios, nrpe

I am trying to configure `NRPE 3.2.0` and it uses the port `5666` to run remote scripts.

When I try to execute the command below, i get this error.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5666/tcp

Error: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -A IN_public_allow -t filter -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5666 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Failed to apply rules. A firewall reload might solve the issue if the firewall has been modified using ip*tables or ebtables.
```

I understand that the chain I am trying to append does not exist, but I don't have a clue about what this chain is or how to create it.

Comment: Have to tried to reload firewall? `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: it worked! thanks :)

Comment: @SergioLaRosa can you write your comment as answer? I will accept it

Comment: sure, just a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reload the firewall with: `firewall-cmd --reload`.